# Lesbian fanfiction: Greek woman whose girlfriend is a Greek goddess, or an alien dressed as one

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction

I read this story in 2011 on Fanfiction.net. It featured a Greek woman and her girlfriend. The girlfriend was either an alien dressed like a Greek goddess or an actual Greek goddess.  It also featured statues and the sort you see in the Minecraft Zeus world.

That's all I remember. I hope it doesn't get put on hold as "too broad."

Comment: Welcome to scifi.se! I've edited your question to be a little more clear, but there's one part I still don't understand. Could you clarify what you mean by "statues and the sort you see in the Minecraft Zeus world", perhaps by providing a link to what you're referencing?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (Fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question)

Comment: Do you remember what it was a fanfiction *of?* That is probably the single biggest piece of information you can provide to narrow it down.

Comment: I think they're implying it's a minecraft fan-fiction.